# New vanity sink drain and plumbing misaligned

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, vanity

I recently installed a new vanity top but now am having issues installing the P-trap back due to the sink drain being in a different position.

It seems the PVC coming out of the wall is glued so I can't seem to unscrew anything there. Any suggestions would be great as this is my first project.

Here are pictures:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The P-trap does seem to have a threaded connection, so might just be a bit of wiggling.  If wiggling does not work, maybe replacement of some glued fittings to threaded.

Comment: Are you positive that it’s glued between the clean out and the wall? I’m hoping for your sake that there’s a threaded attachment at the vent/drain. If not, it seems like you’re going to have to open up the cabinet and the wall and get a new sanitary tee in there.

Comment: @crip659 thanks for the reply. It does come off but the sink drain is too close to where the J needs to connect back. I was able to wiggle and eventually connect it but you can see how it is putting string on the sink drain in these pictures:

https://imgur.com/a/uGuhmNW (imgur is saying this is over 18 content for some reason)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate it kinda seems like it. Here is another closer picture of the pipe near the wall. The yellow looked like glue to me but maybe you can see, let me know if other pictures are helpful.

https://imgur.com/a/XdALB2x

Answer (score 0):

The connection at the base of the Ptrap should not be glued.

Unscrew it and then move the free part to align with the sink tailpiece.

You will need to get a nut and washer for connecting the sink tailpiece and the drain.

I use a [thread paste](https://www.oatey.com/products/oatey-great-white-pipe-joint-compound-with-ptfe--275767012) to help seal the connections for no leaks.

Comment: Sorry my original post left that out. It does unscrew. I was able to wiggle it onto the sink drain but it then causes strain on the sink drain. You can see some more pictures here: https://imgur.com/a/uGuhmNW (ignore the 18+ warning)

Thanks for the reply.

thank